# How do I parse this JSON array into columns with the respective answer?

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a column with JSON in postgresql that has over 5,000 records like this (this is one row/record).

How do I get this parsed into each field id becoming a column (1, 2, 3, etc.) with the respective answer in the column (Answer1, True, Answer3, Answer4, etc.)?

```
[
    {
        "text": "Answer1",
        "type": "text",
        "field": {
            "id": "1",
            "ref": "a",
            "type": "short_text"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "boolean",
        "field": {
            "id": "2",
            "ref": "b",
            "type": "yes_no"
        },
        "boolean": true
    },
    {
        "type": "choices",
        "field": {
            "id": "3",
            "ref": "c",
            "type": "multiple_choice"
        },
        "choices": {
            "ids": [
                "utrjsdf"
            ],
            "refs": [
                "erfghnjm"
            ],
            "labels": [
                "Answer3"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "choices",
        "field": {
            "id": "4",
            "ref": "d",
            "type": "multiple_choice"
        },
        "choices": {
            "ids": [
                "iuyhgfdxs"
            ],
            "refs": [
                "6xcdfghyuio"
            ],
            "labels": [
                "Answer4"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "choices",
        "field": {
            "id": "5",
            "ref": "e",
            "type": "multiple_choice"
        },
        "choices": {
            "ids": [
                "zxcvghjk"
            ],
            "refs": [
                "8mnbvcx"
            ],
            "labels": [
                "Answer5"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "choice",
        "field": {
            "id": "6",
            "ref": "f",
            "type": "multiple_choice"
        },
        "choice": {
            "id": "oiuytre",
            "ref": "dfghjk",
            "label": "Answer6"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "choice",
        "field": {
            "id": "7",
            "ref": "g",
            "type": "multiple_choice"
        },
        "choice": {
            "id": "artyrtyhj",
            "ref": "asdfhgfd",
            "label": "Answer7"
        }
    },
    {
        "text": "Answer8",
        "type": "text",
        "field": {
            "id": "8",
            "ref": "h",
            "type": "long_text"
        }
    },
    {
        "text": "Answer8",
        "type": "text",
        "field": {
            "id": "9",
            "ref": "i",
            "type": "long_text"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you mentioning that! I haven't worked with JSON before and some how in my copy paste/replace info step all those extra quotes got added and it didn't stand out to me. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collating answers from questionnaires that are stored as JSON documents... a recurring question here.

#### Assumptions

1. You just want the question ID and the answer.
2. For `choice` and `choices` questions, the answer is in the `label` field.
3. You're going to do some more processing on the answers, especially in the multiple-choice cases.

#### Solution 1

Since there are a fixed number of question types, each with the answer stored in its own unique way, we can use `COALESCE()` to hunt for one that exists:

```
SELECT r->'field'->>'id' AS id, 
    COALESCE(r->'text', 
        r->'boolean', 
        r->'choices'->'labels', 
        r->'choice'->'label') AS data
FROM 
    (SELECT r FROM foo CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(foo.a) j(r)) t(r)
```

If more control is desired, we can also use a stack of `UNION ALL` queries to pick out the answers based on the question type:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT r FROM foo
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(foo.a) j(r)
)

SELECT r->'field'->>'id' AS id, r->'text' AS data FROM cte WHERE r->>'type' = 'text'
UNION ALL
SELECT r->'field'->>'id', r->'boolean' FROM cte WHERE r->>'type' = 'boolean'
UNION ALL
SELECT r->'field'->>'id', r->'choices'->'labels' FROM cte WHERE r->>'type' = 'choices'
UNION ALL
SELECT r->'field'->>'id', r->'choice'->'label' FROM cte WHERE r->>'type' = 'choice'
```

This is likely the fastest. If you need to filter which rows from the master table are processed, you can add a `WHERE` clause to the source query.

This query returns a row with `id` as `text` and `data` as `jsonb`. I put the answer in `jsonb` format so we don't have to create separately-typed columns and the fundamental types and arrays would be preserved. Otherwise additional processing is required to change the jsonb to something else, especially in the array case.

#### Solution 2

Another way is to use a table-returning function that does the casing iteratively:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION j_convert()
 RETURNS TABLE(id text, data jsonb)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT
AS $function$
DECLARE
    l record;
BEGIN
    FOR l IN
        SELECT r FROM foo CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(foo.a) j(r)
    LOOP
        IF l.r->>'type' = 'text' THEN id = l.r->'field'->>'id'; data = l.r->'text';
        ELSIF l.r->>'type' = 'boolean' THEN id = l.r->'field'->>'id'; data = l.r->'boolean';
        ELSIF l.r->>'type' = 'choices' THEN id = l.r->'field'->>'id'; data = l.r->'choices'->'labels';
        ELSIF l.r->>'type' = 'choice' THEN id = l.r->'field'->>'id'; data = l.r->'choice'->'label';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEXT;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN;
END
$function$
```

Advantages here are that it's easy to use (`SELECT * FROM j_convert();`) and modify with any additional processing. On the downside, this is resource-hungry if the data set is very large. The output is a text `id` column and a jsonb `data` column.

#### Output

The output of both options is something like this, but note the `data` column is actually a jsonb object so what you see is a representation of the actual data (warning: may not be sorted unless you use `ORDER BY`):

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Answer1" |
| 2 | true |
| 3 | ["Answer3"] |
| 4 | ["Answer4"] |
| 5 | ["Answer5"] |
| 6 | "Answer6" |
| 7 | "Answer7" |
| 8 | "Answer8" |
| 9 | "Answer8" |

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and help with this! This is my first time working with JSON/questionnaires so I appreciate your responds and setting me in the right direction for future searches for this type of data.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as Accepted if it was helpful for you.